# Como montar colunas a partir de <ul>?

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho esse código e gostaria que a cada 4 resultados fosse inserido uma `<ul></ul>` para fazer colunas de ***25% de largura*** e obter exatamente 4 colunas. Como posso fazer?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php echo $i; ?>x <strong>R$ <?php echo number_format($preco_parcela, 2, ',', '.');?></strong>
        <?php echo $texto_juros?><?php echo " = R$ " . number_format( $i * $preco_parcela, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução seria utilizar DIVS.

Independente do número de resultados, o layout se adequaria colocando os resultados lado a lado e ainda daria para aplicar um responsivo manualmente ou classes do boostrap (.span3 por ex).

**Exemplo:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    Div com 25% largura e regras para responsivo.
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end content -->
```

**CSS:**

.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px; /*tamanho que vc usa no site. */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content. item {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 10px 1%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content. item {
        width: 48%;
        margin: 10px 1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content. item {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }

}